# Swedish characters decoded incorrectly: is this the API's fault or mine?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I'm sending requests to an API and saving the response text in XML or JSON format.
The response text, fetched with `requests`:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

print(response.text)
```

presents some incorrectly decoded characters, which are always matched to � or `&#65533;` depending on whether I encode the response text to `utf-8` before I save it to file:

```
with open(filename + datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d_%H%M%S") + '.json', 'w',
          encoding='utf-8') as f:
     f.write(response.text)
```

The response header includes `'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'` while the response content specifies that the encoding is `utf-8`.

Now, since the characters are already incorrectly decoded in the response text and they are all matched to the same character (so I have no way to match � back to the original character), it seems to me like this is an error on the API's part. Am I correct, or is this something I can fix?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show `response.headers`.

Comment: Check `response.content` and decode yourself.

Comment: Check `response.encoding` and observe neighbourhood of _garbled_ character(s) in `response.content`…